# Determine Disk Geometry on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, hard-drive

I need to programmatically determine out how many sectors, heads, and cylinders are on a physical disk from Windows XP. Does anyone know the API for determining this? Where might Windows expose this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28VS.85%29.aspx) with control code [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365169%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365171%28VS.85%29.aspx).

There's sample code in MSDN to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363147%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's a control code you can pass to [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365171(VS.85).aspx) to get the physical disk geometry.

Answer (score 1):

WMI is good at this too, I've used it with great success.

```
using( ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass( "Win32_DiskDrive" ) )
{
    using( ManagementObjectCollection physicalDrives = driveClass.GetInstances( ) )
    {
        foreach( ManagementObject drive in physicalDrives )
        {
            string cylinders = ( string )drive["TotalCylinders"];
            // ... etc ...
            drive.Dispose( );
        }
    }
}
```

For a list of additional drive properties you can use, check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx)